# QuickReport for Delphi XE 3

Tags: delphi-xe3, quickreports

I'm migrating a project made in delphi 7 with quickreport 5.05
 to delphi xe3. 
 I will need to update the quickreport to a newer version
 or can I continue with the same version?

Comment: If you have a registered version of QR5, there are downloads available on the registered users page for XE3. If you don't have a registered version, you're going to be out of luck. You should be contacting QR support to ask this sort of question.

Comment: I have noticed that I don't have the QR5. How can I export reports from quickreport to FastReport 5?

Comment: The paid version of FR5 (not the version that comes with XE3, but the full version you can buy) has a utility that will help with the conversion. Contact FR support.

Comment: I understand. Thanks, Ken!